# Problem in creating all default directories while adding a new user account in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: directory, default, useradd

I am facing a bizarre problem recently in Ubuntu 12.04 while adding a new user. User adding command such as `useradd -d  /home/username -s  /bin/bash -m  username` in the terminal only creates a `example-ubuntu` folder in the user's home but not the `Downloads, Documents, Pictures, Music`, etc.

Note that just before this, I had a problem with "login" probably due to interrupted ubuntu updating. So, I fixed the problem by:

1. re-installing "ubuntu-desktop"
2. re-configuring "lightdm"
3. installing "unity and unity-2d" by searching Ubuntu blogs. 
   Now login problem is fixed, but useradd is not.

So, I would really appreciate any help in this matter if anyone knows.

Mahboob

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo adduser <username>
```

Try that instead of useradd.

Make sure it's on

```
sudo sed -i s/enabled=False/enabled=True/g /etc/xdg/user-dirs.conf
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried **adduser** but unfortunately, I get the same result as before. To be noted, before my "login failure" problem "useradd -d ... ... ..." just worked so fine.